# Would this prevent FNV1a 32 bit hash collision?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I am considering the FNV1a 32 bit hash as part of a simple software security and authentication system. I am aware that FNV1a is NOT ideal but it may suit my needs.

I am aware that FNV1a has rather poor collision behavior, but I would like to know if it may be implemented in such a way as to minimize problems. Assuming pass-phrases are hashed in their entirety multiple inputs may have the same output, but what if each character of a pass-phrase is hashed and the hashes are concatenated in a string?

I suppose my questions is, is collision less likely for individual characters than for strings?

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve? Your character wise hashing is no better than ROT13 encryption.

Comment: @CodesInChaos My purpose at the moment is just to learn and plan, so the flaws of such a scheme do mot matter very much for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *"Is collision less likely for individual characters than for strings?"*

The answer to this is **yes**. In fact, experimentally verifying shows that for 8-bit ASCII characters the collision chance with FNV1a is 0. This is however not an impressive feat, seeing that the output is 4 times as large as the input.

However, using this you no longer have a hashing function in the traditional sense. Each character gets replaced by simple substitution table, and becomes 4 times as long.

As for security, this is useless. This is a simple **unkeyed** substitution cipher which can be broken by either statistical analysis within minutes, a good eyeball or even one chosen plaintext. This scheme doesn't follow [Kerckhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which is also very bad.